# MATLAB's smooth function in Java

Tags: java, matlab, smoothing, moving-average

I am in dire need to using a moving average smoothing technique in my current Java project. I would like to achieve the same thing as MATLAB is achieving using `smooth()` function.

Does anyone know whether Apache, or any other library does it? Perhaps there is some code online I could reuse that implements this strategy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving average is just a one line practically. You can find different alternatives [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average). For instance exponential moving average can be implemented as `s(i)=a*y(i)+(1-a)*s(i-1)`, where `y(i)` is the data and `s(i)` is the average.

Comment: I would like to implement the one in the matlab, one that allows certain spans on points considered.

Comment: smooth function looks like standard averaging of a vector. Why don't you just use the `mean` function. For the span you can use standard indexing.

Comment: Yeah, just use a windowed mean.  You have to define your window size and your window overlap (or alternatively window shift) depending on your needs (that would define your "spans")